# Total positivity of order 2 of generalized absolute value density or likelihood ratio order of "shifted" generalized absolute value

Tags: reference-request, total-positivity

If $f$ is the Lebesgue density of a real valued symmetric random variable $X$ (symmetric means $X \overset{d}{=} -X$) then for fixed $u > 0$
$$f^*(v,u) := f(-u -v) + f(-u+v)$$
is the density of $\lvert X + u \rvert$ in $v>0$. In the book *Total Positivity* by Karlin (1968) in Chapter 7 §9 the random variable $\lvert X + u \rvert$ is called *generalized absolute value* and the function $f^*$ (I will refer to $f^*$ as *generalized absolute value density*) is studied in the following context of total positivity.

By total positivity it is meant that for $V,U \subset \Bbb R$ a function $ K : V \times U \to \Bbb R$ is called totally positive of order $r\in \Bbb N$ (often abbreviated by $\mathrm{TP}_r$), if for all choices $v_1 \leq \dotsb  \leq v_r$, $v_i\in V$, $u_1 \leq \dotsb \leq u_r $, $u_i\in U$ we have that
$$\det \begin{pmatrix} K(v_1 ,u_1) & \cdots & K(v_1 , u_r) \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ K(v_r, u_1) & \cdots & K(v_r , u_r)\end{pmatrix} \geq 0.$$

In this context consider the following facts (which can be found in the mentioned Chapter 7 §9):

Fact 1. The class of symmetric random variables for which the generalized absolute value density is $\mathrm{TP}_r$ for $V = U = \Bbb R_+$ is closed under addition/convolution. More precisely, if $X$, $Y$ are independent and have symmetric densities $f$ and $g$ and $f^*$ and $g^*$ are $\mathrm{TP}_r$ then the generalized absolute value density of $X+Y$ is $\mathrm{TP}_r$. The proof uses the so called *basic composition formula* in Chapter 3 §1 and is a standard tool in this area.

Fact 2. If $f$ is a Polya frequency function (this means $f$ is a Polya frequency function of order $r$ for all $r$ ($\mathrm{PF}_r$), where $\mathrm{PF}_r$ in turn means that $K(v,u) = f(v-u)$ is $\mathrm{TP}_r$ for $V= U = \Bbb R$), then $f^*$ is $\mathrm{TP}_r$ for all $r$.

**My Concern:**

I am especially interested in the set of symmetric density functions (and even particularly with compact support) whose generalized absolute value density is $\mathrm{TP}_2$ because of the following.

Considering the likelihood ratio order between random variables (you can look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068624/monotone-likelihood-ratio-without-densities/4058975#4058975 for the definition) one can prove that for a symmetric random variable with density $f$ the following three statements are in fact equivalent:

(i) $f^*$ is $\mathrm{TP}_2$

(ii) For any pair independent from $X$ of symmetric real valued random variables $Y$, $Z$ with $\lvert Y \rvert $ smaller than $\lvert Z \rvert $ in the likelihood ratio order we have that $\lvert X + \lvert Y\rvert\rvert$ is smaller than $\lvert X + \lvert Z \rvert \rvert$ in the likelihood ratio order. In other words: The linear integral operator $T$ with integral kernel/ kernel function $f^*$ preserves the ordering.

(iii) $\lvert X + u_1 \rvert $ is smaller than $\lvert X + u_2\rvert $ in the likelihood ratio order for any ordered pair $0 < u_1 < u_2$.

Especially (ii) makes clear that the situation of $f^*$ being $\mathrm{TP}_2$ is the counterpart of $f$ being a Polya frequency function of order $2$. By counterpart I mean that the $\mathrm{PF}_2$ densities (not necessarily symmetric) are exactly the densities by which the usual convolution integral operator with kernel $K(v,u) = f(v-u)$ preserves the "one-sided" ordering, if $Y$ is smaller than $Z$ in the likelihood ratio order.

The kernel function $f(v-u)$ has been intensively studied. In the "one-sided" situation there is the following well-known convenient characterization of $\mathrm{PF}_2$ densities:

$$f \text{ is } \mathrm{PF}_2 \text{ and measurable } \Leftrightarrow \log \circ \;f \text{ is concave}$$

Now back to the "two-sided" case: Has the kernel function $f^*$ been studied as well?

**Which sufficient and necessary conditions for $f^*$ being $\mathrm{TP}_2$ are known?**

By Fact 2 we have a sufficient condition for $f^*$ being $\mathrm{TP}_2$. But it turns out that this is a very strong condition.The following two facts can be found in the already mentioned book. First, a Polya frequency function of all orders cannot have compact support. Second, in the symmetric case its Laplace transform has the form
$$\frac{e^{\mu s^2}}{\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1- \lambda_i^2 s^2)},\qquad \text{for } 0< \mu + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i^2 < \infty, \mu \geq 0$$
which intuitively means that $f$ is the convolution of countably many densities of  centered gaussian random variables and continuous laplacian random variables. This makes sense in view of Fact 1 since one can prove that for both cases (gaussian and laplacian) the generalized absolute value density is $\mathrm{TP}_r$ for all $r$.

In the case of $f$ having compact support the set of functions where $f^*$ is $\mathrm{TP}_2$ is not empty. I computed by hand that in the case $f(x) = \frac 1 2 \Bbb 1_{[-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2]}(x) \cos (x)$ the generalized absolute value density $f^*$ is $\mathrm{TP}_2$, which seems to be an extreme case, since for $0 < u_1 < u_2$, $0 < v_1 < v_2$ such that $v_2+u_2 \leq \frac \pi 2$ we have
$$\det \begin{pmatrix} f^* (v_1, u_1) & f^* (v_1, u_2)\\ f^* (v_2, u_1) & f^* (v_2, u_2) \end{pmatrix} = 0.$$